# DocuSign for Salesforce -Open in new window

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

We currently have DocuSign integrated with Salesforce. When users use the custom DocuSign button the DocuSign process starts within the salesforce window. We'd like this whole thing to pop out into a new window. I found this article: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-admin-guide/Content/admin-guide/console-buttons.htm

But I'm not a coding expert and I was unable to implement it correctly. When I click the button I now receive a pop-up error from Chrome "Invalid left-hand side in assignment."

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();


//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC= '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL='';var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//

RSL = '4';
RROS = '1,2,3,4';
CES = '{!CanaryAMS__Policy__c.CanaryAMS__Contact_for_Policy__c}';
CCRM = 'Signer 1~Customer;Signer 2~CSR';
CCTM = 'Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer';
CRL = 'Email~{!CanaryAMS__Policy__c.contact_email__c};LastName~{!CanaryAMS__Policy__c.CanaryAMS__Contact_for_Policy__c};Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1;AccessCode~{!CanaryAMS__Policy__c.DocuSignAccessCode__c},Email~{!$User.Email};Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2;FirstName~{!$User.LastName};LastName~{!$User.FirstName},LoadDefaultContacts~1';



function inIframe () {
  try {
    return window.self !== window.top;
  } catch (e) {
    return true;
  }
}


if(inIframe()){window.open("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?nw=1"+DSEID=0&SourceID={!CanaryAMS__Policy__c.Id}"&+RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES, "Popup", "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, directories=1, toolbar=1, titlebar=1, width=1200");
} else {
window.location.href="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!CanaryAMS__Policy__c.Id}"+RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! paste the code in the question and then highlight the text and click the code block button

Comment: Posted the code sorry about that.